can't open scp://… URLs, neovim instead creates local folders
I think I'm supposed to be able to
nvim scp://myhost_as_configured_in_ssh//home/marcus/somefile

However, even as ssh myhost_as_configured_in_ssh cat /home/marcus/somefile works flawlessly, I simply get an empty buffer when I run the above nvim command line.
:writing that buffer creates an scp: directory in the current directory, a home inside that, a marcus inside that, and in that directory, somefile.
I'm using NVIM 0.10.1 on Fedora 40, and astronvim to manage my configuration. the log file at $NVIM_LOG_FILE gets touched, but contains nothing.
:checkhealth shows no fundamental problems; output of that.
How do I access files via SSH? Can I get the ability to open scp:// URLs?

It doesn’t look like Neovim ripped out netrw; are the relevant autocommands setup?

@D.BenKnoble how could I check?

Something like :autocmd, though that will be hard to sift through. You could also put them in a buffer :new | put =execute('autocomd')
